# how to detect change in playbackrate value (1x,1.5x ,2x) in video js..

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, video.js

```
videojs.player().playbackRate();
```

it gives me the current value of playbackrate... 
but how to get changed playbackRate value onclick in PlaybackRateMenuButton??

[PlaybackRateMenuButton Handle click](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/playback-rate-menu-button.html#MethodshandleClick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lol just onclick function solve this..

```
$(".vjs-menu-item").click(function () {
                    console.log(videoJs.player().playbackRate());
                });
```